# Android: ICS Spell-Checking not working

Tags: android

I've just tried out my application on a physical device running ICS for the first time and much to my surprise and dismay the spell check that underlined misspelled words in the emulator is not working.  The device in question is a HTC One S.  The spelling correction does appear to be there in other applications.  It's always been there in my application when running on the emulator.

I've found nothing to suggest there is anything I need to turn on to get the spell check to work and the fact it works in the emulator but not in a real device is quite alarming. Is there something else I am missing?